# Does obj.save() in save_model() in admin.ModelAdmin call save() in models.Model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I overrided **"save()"** in **"Person(models.Model)" class** as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, I also overrided **"save_model()"** with **"pass"** in **"PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)" class** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pass
        # super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

But, I couldn't add **"Steve Jobs"** even though ***The Person “Steve Jobs” was added successfully.*** was displayed as shown below:

[image]

Next, for **"save_model()"** in **"PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)" class**, I replaced **"pass"** with **"super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)"** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # pass
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Now, I could add **"Steve Jobs"** as shown below:

[image]

So, I checked [**save_model() on Django repository**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e30d6678421b7573a1995f61521f14348c9b2a17/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1222) on **GitHub**. Then, in **"save_model()"** in **ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin)" class**, **"obj.save()"** is called as shown below:

```py
# "django/django/contrib/admin/options.py"

# ...

class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):

    # ...

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """
        Given a model instance save it to the database.
        """
        obj.save() # Here
```

So, does **"obj.save()"** call **"save()"** in **"Person(models.Model)" class**?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** "object.save()" will call the method of that object which is Person(models.Model). You can also see in ModelAdmin code [enter link description here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e30d6678421b7573a1995f61521f14348c9b2a17/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L614) where they clearly state that **ModelAdmin** just adds admin panel-related functionality to the given **Model**. And "save_model" is use models built in the **save** method because **ModelAdmin** does not inherit from the model(Person(models.Model). For more details, you can check in **Django official documentation** [enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects).